# Is it possible to override node_modules/protracor/config.json from the project package.json?

Tags: json, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I have edited my protractor config.json file to update the default version that it installs.  When I run this, the desired latest version is downloaded into my project folder.

I want to extend this solution to other project users, but editing their local config.json may not be an option (the protractor files are only generated on npm install).  Is there a way to specify the updated version within the project (package.json) that will override the specified version?

Snippet from the protractor/config.json

```
"webdriverVersions": {
    "chromedriver": "xx",
    }
```

I'm also changing a value in the protractor/bin/webdriver-manager to point to a 64.zip version of the chromedriver, rather than the default 32.zip (this one does not exist)  Any ideas on how to override that too would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of Protractor (4.0.10) has a fix for the chromedriver download issue. This should download the latest chromedriver (2.25). Please update to the latest.